# Update double nested Arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update nested arrays value in Mongo DB, but not able to update

In the below example, I want to set

`methodinfo.OutputFieldInfo.isPrimaryKey` to `true`

where

```
{
  "parametername" = "MajesticID"
  "fullyqualifiedparamname" = "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-MajesticID__Int64__"
}
```

Sample documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1001",
    "userid": -1,
    "customerid": 95,
    "methodinfo": [
      {
        "servicename": "Service1",
        "methodname": "Method1",
        "assettype": "Hotel",
        "assetname": "GTA SPORTS",
        "timeproperty": "",
        "timeoverlapdays": NumberLong(2),
        "inputfieldsinfo": [],
        "OutputFieldInfo": [
          {
            "parametername": "FirstName",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-FirstName__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "ID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-ID__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "LastName",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-LastName__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "MajesticID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-MajesticID__Int64__",
            **"isPrimaryKey": false**
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Latitude",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-Position__Position__-Latitude__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Longitude",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-Position__Position__-Longitude__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "DriverAlarmText",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-DriverAlarmText__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "GeoZoneSeq",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-GeoZoneSeq__Int64__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "GeoZoneTNR",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-GeoZoneTNR__Int64__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Name",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-Name__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Radius",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoZone__GeoZoneResult_v2__-Radius__Int32__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "GeoFenceID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoFenceID__Int64__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "GeoFenceName",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-GeoFence__GeoFenceResult_v2__-GeoFenceName__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Latitude",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Position__Position__-Latitude__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Longitude",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Position__Position__-Longitude__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Code",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Trailer__IdentifierVehicleResult__-Code__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Filter",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Trailer__IdentifierVehicleResult__-Filter__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "ID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Trailer__IdentifierVehicleResult__-ID__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "LicensePlate",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Trailer__IdentifierVehicleResult__-LicensePlate__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "MajesticID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Trailer__IdentifierVehicleResult__-MajesticID__Int64__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Code",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Vehicle__IdentifierVehicleResult__-Code__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Filter",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Vehicle__IdentifierVehicleResult__-Filter__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "ID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Vehicle__IdentifierVehicleResult__-ID__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "LicensePlate",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Vehicle__IdentifierVehicleResult__-LicensePlate__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "MajesticID",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Vehicle__IdentifierVehicleResult__-MajesticID__Int64__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "AlarmMessageStatus",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-AlarmMessageStatus__enumAlarmMessageStatus__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "AlarmMessageType",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-AlarmMessageType__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Date",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Date__DateTime__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Message",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Message__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "ErrorCode",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Errors__Error______-ErrorCode__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "ErrorCodeExplanation",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Errors__Error______-ErrorCodeExplanation__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Field",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Errors__Error______-Field__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Value",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Errors__Error______-Value__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Field",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Warnings__Warning______-Field__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Value",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Warnings__Warning______-Value__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "WarningCode",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Warnings__Warning______-WarningCode__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "WarningCodeExplenation",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Warnings__Warning______-WarningCodeExplenation__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Executiontime",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-Executiontime__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "cronstring": "0 57 14 ? * *",
    "isenabled": true,
    "createddate": ISODate("2021-03-18T14:56:36.594Z"),
    "modifieddate": ISODate("2021-03-18T17:32:46.817Z"),
    "datasetname": "22",
    "isDatasetProcessedBefore": false,
    "historicaldataenddate": null,
    "historicaldatastartdate": null
  },
  {
    "_id": "1002",
    "userid": -1,
    "customerid": 23,
    "methodinfo": [
      {
        "servicename": "Service1",
        "methodname": "Method2",
        "assettype": "ByTrailer",
        "assetname": "DateTimeRange",
        "timeproperty": "DateTimeRange",
        "timeoverlapdays": NumberLong(2),
        "inputfieldsinfo": [
          {
            "parametername": "Id",
            "type": "String",
            "value": "2",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method2-RequestParameters-FileSelection-Files__IdentifierFile______-Id__String__"
          }
        ],
        "OutputFieldInfo": [
          {
            "parametername": "Executiontime",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method2-ResponseParameters-GetFileResult-Executiontime__Double__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "FileBase64",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-GetFileResult-FileResultItems__FileResultItem______-FileBase64__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          },
          {
            "parametername": "Value",
            "fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-GetFileResult-Warnings__Warning______-Value__String__",
            "isPrimaryKey": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "cronstring": "0 35 14 ? * *",
    "isenabled": true,
    "createddate": ISODate("2021-03-19T14:34:29.414Z"),
    "modifieddate": null,
    "datasetname": "1111",
    "isDatasetProcessedBefore": false
  }
]
```

I have used the below syntax to update

```
db.collection.update({
  "methodinfo.methodname": "Method1",
  "methodinfo.OutputFieldInfo.parametername": "MajesticID"
},
{
  $set: {
    "methodinfo.$.OutputFieldInfo.$[elem].isPrimaryKey": true,
    
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.$.fullyqualifiedparamname": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-MajesticID__Int64__"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

I have placed the code here
https://mongoplayground.net/p/qeeHVaxRcXn

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, but as `methodInfo` is alsay an array, you can't use the main filters, and you have to define another array filter like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "methodinfo.$[method].OutputFieldInfo.$[output].isPrimaryKey": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "method.methodname": {
        "$eq": "Method1"
      }
    },
    {
      "output.parametername": {
        "$eq": "MajesticID"
      },
      "output.fullyqualifiedparamname": {
        "$eq": "Service1-Method1-ResponseParameters-Method1-PersonalMessagesV2-Driver__IdentifierPerson__-MajesticID__Int64__"
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/vx8E1Dx6Vej](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vx8E1Dx6Vej)